# Is it possible to use concatenated values from 2 columns as a table name in from clause

Tags: oracle, select, oracle10g, sqlplus

I'd like to concatenate values from 2 selected columns and use a result as table name for another select statement:

```
select a.ColumnA,
       a.ColumnB, 
       b.ColumnG, 
       (a.ColumnA || '.' || a.ColumnB) "TABLENAME"
       (select t.ColumnX from TABLENAME t where t.ColumnY = 'whatever') "GOAL"
from
       table a,
       table b,
where
       ....
```

So assuming that

```
table a:
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ...
    dev    town      15

table b:
ColumnF ColumnG ColumnH ...
    aaa    bbb      ccc
```

somewhere there exists table town in schema dev that can be queried using name dev.town:

```
table dev.town:
ColumnX   ColumnY ColumnZ ...
    Joe  whatever      Mr
```

So "my query" returns

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnG TABLENAME GOAL
--------------------------------------
    dev    town     bbb  dev.town  Joe
```

Is there a way to get the results I need?

Thanks.

Comment: I've got no experience with Oracle, but in the databases I am familiar with this is not possible in one query.

Comment: I don't need to do that in one query as long as I get my final set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Not in an SQL statement in Oracle.
If you dived in PL/SQL, then you could use an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement to dynamically generate the required table.

Comment: I've never worked much with PL/SQL so it looks like it's time to take a fast track course. Thanks for help.